# How to add validation in nested form array?

Tags: angular, validation, formarray

I have a problem on validation on calculation. The total quota should be sum of each quota. However, this total quota should be input by user (not calculation). If all quota are sum and also not same value as total quota, it will trigger a validation when user click save button. As I can't find any solution in form array validation, is it able to implement on it?

Here's a StackBlitz: [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rdddth?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner formArray is valid if the quotes sum a value that belong to the formGroup. So you need validate the formGroup, not the formArray

```
this.data.sessionList.forEach((x) => {
  this.sessionListFormArr.push(
    this.fb.group(
      {
        sessionId: x.sessionId,
        totalQuota: x.totalQuota,
        enrolTypeList: this.setenrolTypeList(x),
      },
      
      { validator: this.checkTotlalQuotaValidator() }
    )
  );
});
```

And the custom validator is simply

```
  checkTotlalQuotaValidator(form: FormGroup) {
    const totalQuota: number = +form.get('totalQuota').value;
    const subQuota:any[]= form.get('enrolTypeList').value;
    const sumSubquota=subQuota.reduce((a,b)=>a+b.subQuota,0)

    return sumSubquota==totalQuota?null:{error:'should meet the sum'}
  }
```

Now you can use this error in your .html like

```
   <div class="col-lg-3 mb-1" style="color:blue">
                        Total Quota: {{sessionListFormArr.controls[i].errors|json}}
   </div>
```

And

```
<button [disabled]="sessionListessionDynamicForm.invalid" 
      (click)="checkTotal()">save</button>
```

Well, a Validator is executed by defect each time the FormControl or the FormGroup change, so Angular execute severals time the function. You can indicate that this is executed only on submit -in this case you can not use [disabled] in the button-

```
{ validators: [this.checkTotlalQuotaValidator],updateOn:'submit' }
```

NOTE: You should use `form` -no `<div>` when you has a Form and the button should be inside the "form"

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I just following your solution. It seem to be only validate in ngOnInit. If I keep changing to add assigning more quota/ delete quota, the validation in Total Quota is not update. It also keep disable in save button.  Is that any missing in my code?   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3cgsxf?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to validate the quota.

```
checkTotal() {
 this.sessionListessionDynamicForm.value.sessionList.forEach((session, index) => {
   let sum = 0;
   session.enrolTypeList.forEach((list) => {
     sum += +list.subQuota;
   });
   if(sum != session.totalQuota){
     console.log('session',index+1, 'has mismatch')
     //add setError code here
   }
 });
}
```

You can add errors to the sessions having mismatch using setError by adding code at marked position in code

Comment: sounds good the above code

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your help. I checked it is works. But I have a problem on it. When there are 2 session, one session is match and another session is mismatch. I would like to validate all session after call a submit function. Now, It seem to be pass a success session but there has also mismatch session. How to handle the validation checking in all session ?